# Opening Link via New Window from Javascript Select List

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm not sure what's the issue that is causing that error message when I try debugging with Firebug.  Everything looks good to me.

Current Issue:

```
$("#SlideList option:selected") is null
```

Select Box Code (abridged) :

```
<select id="SlideList" name="D1" style="width: 130px;"> 
  <option value = "Numbers.pdf" >Numbers</option>
 </select>
 <img src="Button.png" onclick="SlidePDFOpen()" />
```

Javascript:

```
function SlidePDFOpen() {
window.open($("#SlideList option:selected").val());
}
```

Comment: I don't get an error with your code. It tries to open numbers.pdf in a new window. Do you have the full page source

Comment: Here is the source : [http://137.112.170.193/askroseJoomla/index.php/112]

Comment: It doesnt look like you are including jquery in the page. My test was by including jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a jquery selector but you don't have jquery included in the page. 
The error you are getting therefore makes sense as the page can't find the function val().

At the very least with jquery you would get an empty string.

Comment: What would be the cause of the current code not getting Numbers.pdf and reporting null instead though?